# Invoke NewtonSoft SerializeObject and DeserializeObject methods via reflection to work around version mismatch

Tags: json.net

We have a client DLL that has a simple JSON helper built against NewtonSoft ver.9 to help with serialization and deserialization. We want to consume this DLL in another project (owned by a partner team) but that team uses NewtonSoft ver.6 across the board. This results in build errors due to the different versions of NewtonSoft binding. And it is out of scope to upgrade the consuming project to ver.9.

**Does anyone have a solution for such scenarios?**

I tried to make my JSON wrapper not explicitly link at build time and instead use Reflection to invoke the NewtonSoft methods at run-time.

Here is my DelayLoadedJsonHelper code that implements this:

```
namespace Test
{
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

/// <summary>
/// Helper class for serializing and deserializing JSON using a runtime binding to the NewtonSoft Json binary
/// shipped along with our package.
/// This allows the our code to use a specific version of NewtonSoft irrespective of the NewtonSoft
/// version that is being consumed by the code consuming the our package.
/// The NewtonSoft binary is shipped with our package in a sub-folder named PrivateNewtonSoft and is explicitly
/// loaded from that sub-folder from the current directory of the executing process.
/// </summary>
public class DelayLoadedJsonHelper
{                                       
    private static readonly string SubFolderName = "PrivateNewtonSoft";
    private static readonly string NewtonSoftJsonDllName = "NewtonSoft.Json.Dll";

    private static Assembly TargetNewtonSoftAssembly;
    private static object CustomJsonSerializerSettings = null;
    private static MethodInfo SerializeObjectMethod = null;
    private static MethodInfo DeserializeObjectMethod = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Static constructor to initialize the delay loaded NewtonSoft dependencies.
    /// </summary>
    static DelayLoadedJsonHelper()
    {
        // Load the private version of the NewtonSoft binary
        // ------------------------------------------------
        string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        string targetAssemblyPath = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, SubFolderName, NewtonSoftJsonDllName);
        DelayLoadedJsonHelper.TargetNewtonSoftAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(targetAssemblyPath);

        // Get the enum value for NullValueHandling.Ignore
        // ------------------------------------------------
        Type nullValueHandlingType = DelayLoadedJsonHelper.TargetNewtonSoftAssembly.GetType("Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling",
                                                                                            throwOnError: true,
                                                                                            ignoreCase: true);
        var nullValueHandlingIgnore = Enum.Parse(nullValueHandlingType, "Ignore");

        // Get the enum value for Formatting.None
        // ------------------------------------------------
        Type formattingType = DelayLoadedJsonHelper.TargetNewtonSoftAssembly.GetType("Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting",
                                                                                     throwOnError: true,
                                                                                     ignoreCase: true);
        var formattingNone = Enum.Parse(formattingType, "None");

        // Instantiate the DefaultContractResolver object
        // ------------------------------------------------
        Type defaultContractResolverType = DelayLoadedJsonHelper.TargetNewtonSoftAssembly.GetType("Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver",
                                                                                     throwOnError: true,
                                                                                     ignoreCase: true);
        var defaultContractResolverInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(defaultContractResolverType);

        // Generate the custom JsonSerializerSettings object and set the properties.
        // This custom JsonSerializerSettings will be used when invoking the SerializeObject
        // and DeserializeObject methods.
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Type jsonSerializerSettingsType = DelayLoadedJsonHelper.TargetNewtonSoftAssembly.GetType("Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings",
                                                                         throwOnError: true,
                                                                         ignoreCase: true);

        DelayLoadedJsonHelper.CustomJsonSerializerSettings = Activator.CreateInstance(jsonSerializerSettingsType);

        jsonSerializerSettingsType.GetProperty("NullValueHandling").SetValue(DelayLoadedJsonHelper.CustomJsonSerializerSettings,
                                                                             nullValueHandlingIgnore,
                                                                             null);

        jsonSerializerSettingsType.GetProperty("Formatting").SetValue(DelayLoadedJsonHelper.CustomJsonSerializerSettings,
                                                                      formattingNone,
                                                                      null);

        jsonSerializerSettingsType.GetProperty("ContractResolver").SetValue(DelayLoadedJsonHelper.CustomJsonSerializerSettings,
                                                                            defaultContractResolverInstance,
                                                                            null);

        // Get the SerializeObject and DeserializeObject methods
        // -----------------------------------------------------
        Type jsonConvert = DelayLoadedJsonHelper.TargetNewtonSoftAssembly.GetType("Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert",
                                                                                  throwOnError: true,
                                                                                  ignoreCase: true);

        DelayLoadedJsonHelper.SerializeObjectMethod = jsonConvert.GetMethods()
                                                                 .Single(m => string.Equals(m.Name, "SerializeObject")
                                                                         && m.GetParameters().Length == 2
                                                                         && m.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == typeof(object)
                                                                         && m.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType == jsonSerializerSettingsType);

        DelayLoadedJsonHelper.DeserializeObjectMethod = jsonConvert.GetMethods()
                                                                   .Single(m => string.Equals(m.Name, "DeserializeObject")
                                                                           && m.IsGenericMethodDefinition
                                                                           && m.GetParameters().Length == 2
                                                                           && m.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == typeof(string)
                                                                           && m.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType == jsonSerializerSettingsType);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Serialize an object to a json string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">the object to serialize</param>
    /// <returns>json string</returns>
    public static string SerializeObject(object obj)
    {
        return DelayLoadedJsonHelper.SerializeObjectMethod.Invoke(null, 
                                                                  new object[] {
                                                                                obj,
                                                                                DelayLoadedJsonHelper.CustomJsonSerializerSettings
                                                                               })
                                                          .ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deserialize a json string to C# object
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">the type of the object</typeparam>
    /// <param name="json">the json string</param>
    /// <returns>an object of type T</returns>
    public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string json)
    {
        var genericMethod = DelayLoadedJsonHelper.DeserializeObjectMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { typeof(T) });
        return (T) genericMethod.Invoke(null,
                                        new object[] {
                                                        json,
                                                        DelayLoadedJsonHelper.CustomJsonSerializerSettings
                                                     });
    }
}
}
```

This works fine for all standard serializations and deserializations.

But one of the consuming projects uses the Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault REST API. And the serialized Secret data type cannot be deserialized by this DelayLoadedJsonHelper.

But if I directly compile against NewtonSoft and invoke the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject on the REST API response, it works just fine.

Here is a quick unit-test implementation that shows the error. Npte that you have to link to Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.dll for the Secret class. We are currently using ver 1.0.0 of this nuget pkg.

```
[TestMethod]
public void DeserializeKeyVaultResponse()
{
    string testJson = "{\"value\":\"_be07-4342-afa6-46696fe3c69c\",\"id\":\"https://test-vault.vault.azure.net/secrets/sqlLogin-test3-Password2/003d384c\",\"attributes\":{\"enabled\":true,\"created\":1447207748,\"updated\":1447207748},\"tags\":{\"Name\":\"Test3\",\"Param1\":\"para1: 62df9b2b-089e-41a8-acff-d05dcec08ad4\",\"Param2\":\"para2: 082d8fa2-14ca-444f-b87d-5564b1f6a4db\",\"Param3\":\"para3: f88df110-543a-45a7-8b44-991e3d859386\",\"Param4\":\"para4: d9d5e3b6-250f-4ab6-8aea-a501004bc95e\",\"Param5\":\"para5: a1065260-a8d2-4001-945e-db0c8830b749\"}}";
    var deserialized = DelayLoadedJsonHelper.DeserializeObject<Secret>(testJson);
    Assert.IsNotNull(deserialized);
}
```

This fails with the following error:

*Message: Test method DelayLoadedJsonHelperTests.DeserializeKeyVaultResponse threw exception: 
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: 1. Path 'attributes.created', line 1, position 164.*

The same test passes successfully when directly using the NewtonSoft JsonConvert method (i.e. when directly complied against NewtonSoft):

```
[TestMethod]
public void DeserializeKeyVaultResponseUsingNewtonSoftDirectly()
{
    // Deserialize directly using compiled NewtonSoft.
    // These are the same settings used by custom SerailizerSettings
    // in DelayLoadedJsonHelper
    JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        Formatting = Formatting.None,
        ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver(),
    };

    string testJson = "{\"value\":\"_be07-4342-afa6-46696fe3c69c\",\"id\":\"https://test-vault.vault.azure.net/secrets/sqlLogin-test3-Password2/003d384c\",\"attributes\":{\"enabled\":true,\"created\":1447207748,\"updated\":1447207748},\"tags\":{\"Name\":\"Test3\",\"Param1\":\"para1: 62df9b2b-089e-41a8-acff-d05dcec08ad4\",\"Param2\":\"para2: 082d8fa2-14ca-444f-b87d-5564b1f6a4db\",\"Param3\":\"para3: f88df110-543a-45a7-8b44-991e3d859386\",\"Param4\":\"para4: d9d5e3b6-250f-4ab6-8aea-a501004bc95e\",\"Param5\":\"para5: a1065260-a8d2-4001-945e-db0c8830b749\"}}";
    var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Secret>(testJson);
    Assert.IsNotNull(deserialized);
}
```

The issue seems to be that the ***Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Secret*** object has a custom DateTime implementation of Unix epoch and how that is represented in Json. You can see the details of that using ILSPY against version 1.0.0 of the Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault package (available here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault/)

I am stumped why Deserialize invocation via Reflection fails while the compiled invocation works. I suspect there is some other initialization that my DelayLoadedJsonHelper is missing.

**Does anyone have an ideas on how I can fix this?**
Thanks!

Comment: Would you be able to share an [mcve] which demonstrates the problem you are having?  It would be a lot easier for us to help if we could see some code.

Comment: Sorry for the rookie mistake. I have edited my original post with the code and details on how to repro the error.